# How do you implement React Devtools support for a custom React renderer?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

There is no documentation on how to integrate React Devtools into a custom React renderer, and official React renderers such as React DOM and React Native take a bespoke approach to integrating React Devtools that makes studying them difficult (and likely fruitless).

[One article](http://iamdustan.com/2016/02/19/react-devtools-renderer-integration/) exists on this topic, but refers to an out-of-date API (so I won't bother quoting from it).

[React Hardware](https://github.com/iamdustan/react-hardware/blob/f687786aa40cfc1af9a0b9572e95b10754119e5d/src/devtools/setupDevtools.js)'s implementation provides a basis for study, but it is not clear that it works anymore (as the entry file, `InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js` is not imported anywhere in the codebase anymore, and furthermore [imports files that no longer exist](https://github.com/iamdustan/react-hardware/blob/f687786aa40cfc1af9a0b9572e95b10754119e5d/src/devtools/setupDevtools.js#L65) in the repository or `node_modules`).

At the very least, I can see that WebSocket communication is going to be involved. My custom renderer is a cross-platform one for iOS and Android; will I need to install a WebSockets library for each of these platforms (which I believe makes most sense), or do the WebSockets merely run on the Node.js-based packager server?

What are the minimal steps needed to integrate `react-devtools-core` (as of `v3.6.1`) into my custom React renderer?